# Unable to call ng-click function using angularjs google map

Tags: php, angularjs, google-maps

I am using angularJS google map API. When the user clicks on infowindow "hit me" link i need to show text outside of google map.

My code is below
    
    
    Cart One

```
//AngularJS code
var cities = [
{
    city : 'Toronto',
    desc : 'This is the best city in the world!',
    lat : 43.7000,
    long : -79.4000
},
{
    city : 'New York',
    desc : 'This city is aiiiiite!',
    lat : 40.6700,
    long : -73.9400
},
{
    city : 'Chicago',
    desc : 'This is the second best city in the world!',
    lat : 41.8819,
    long : -87.6278
},
{
    city : 'Los Angeles',
    desc : 'This city is live!',
    lat : 34.0500,
    long : -118.2500
},
{
    city : 'Las Vegas',
    desc : 'Sin City...\'nuff said!',
    lat : 36.0800,
    long : -115.1522
}
];

//Angular App Module and Controller
var investup = angular.module('mapsApp', [])
investup.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
}

$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

$scope.markers = [];

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var createMarker = function (info){

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
        title: info.city
    });
    marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2><a href="" ng-click="show_cart_one()">Hit Me</a>' + marker.content); //calling to ng-click function
        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
    });

    $scope.markers.push(marker);

}  

for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
    createMarker(cities[i]);
}

$scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
    e.preventDefault();
    google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
}


$scope.cart_one = false;//by default its false
$scope.show_cart_one = function() //When user clicks on "hit me"
{
    alert("Hi");
    $scope.cart_one = true;
}

});
```

Please help me to sort this issue. I'am newbie to angularjs.

Comment: Which API? http://ngmap.github.io/ or https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps or something else?

Comment: So, you are clicking on that H2 `marker.title` and nothing happens? Did you breakpoint on `show_cart_one()"` in the browser's developer console to see if it was called?

Comment: In that Plunk, ng-click calls openInfoWindow(), which does not match the code posted above

Comment: Yes, i modified it. Shall i give my code Plunk ?

Comment: The two should be consistent, so that people can help you. if you post two version of the code, which should they look at? And what exactly is the problem? That the ng-click action does not seem to be executed?